# Как вставить картинку RichTextBox из буфера обмена?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="text_rich" >
    <FlowDocument >
        <Paragraph/>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

При копировании картинки (файла) с диска не работает. Работает только при копировании картинки из текстового документа .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вставляется из файла а как из буфера?

Так происходит вставка из файла а этот файл-картинка нужен из буфера

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"z:\DOWNLOADS\avatar145693_6.gif"));
Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap);
text_rich.Paste();
```

Comment: А Ctrl-V не подходит?

Comment: нет..................

Comment: Почему? Объясните (наверное, лучше прямо в вопросе).

Comment: не работает Ctrl-V - ничего не происходит. В контекстном меню richtextbox не активна вставка

Comment: Непонятно. Вам нужно вставить через UI? Это у меня работает при помощи обыкновенного Ctrl-V. Или вам нужно вставить программным путём? Делайте просто `text_rich.Paste();`

Comment: любым способом.

Comment: Дайте воспроизводящий пример. У меня ваш XAML работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYLT5.gif

Comment: Можно получить ваш проект в архиве.? проверю у себя.

Comment: Сейчас организую, уберу лишнее.

Comment: Вот: https://mega.nz/#!lgE1CYpD!eHaRJzRmmuyMPFXfjYv5QWt-eoV59kiQwXve_X3qc48

Comment: При копировании картинки (файла) с диска не работает. Работает только при копировании картинки из текстового документа

Comment: Э, что вы делаете! Вы копируете не картинку, а **файл**. Так оно не вставляется никуда, попробуйте другие программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так картинки вставляется:

```
        //Если у нас в буфере не было рисунка, но возможно был скопирован 
        //файл рисунка в буфер, то
        //Создаем список в который поместим все скопированные
        // имена файлов из буфера
        List<string> addFileName = new List<string>();
        //помещаем
        foreach (var filename in Clipboard.GetFileDropList())
        {
            //
            string ext = (Path.GetExtension(filename)).ToLower();
            if (ext == ".bmp" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".tif" || ext == ".tiff" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".wmf" || ext == ".emf")
            {
                addFileName.Add(filename.ToString());

                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename));
                Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap);
                text_rich.Paste();
            }
        }
        //Проверяем если имен файлов нет, то выводим об этом сообщение
        if (addFileName.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not image");
            return;
        }
        //Очищаем буфер
        //Clipboard.Clear();
```

Comment: Если вы вставляете программным путём, то вам не нужен по идее буфер.

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь что-то типа этого:

```
   private void createImage(Control item)
    {   
        Hashtable image = new Hashtable(1);
        image.Add(item,yourproject.Properties.Resources.yourpicturename);
        Clipboard.SetImage((Image)image[item]);
        ((RichTextBox)item).Paste();
    }
```

Comment: Эээ... А зачем в коде `Hashtable`?

Comment: @VladD код не мой. Нашёл в гугле. Да это излише

Comment: Ну, вы ж публикуете под своими именем? Вы за него и в ответе.